# How to configure and use Auth-0 in Angular4

Tags: angular, authentication

```
How to configure Auth-0 in Angular 4 Application,
```

i have installed latest version of angular-cli , but i have found only Auth0 for angular2 only .

Comment: It will work same as in angular 2 because angular 4 retains the backward compatibility & not like release of angular 2 against angularjs 1. So Use it & it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is starting point, follow the setup for Angular 2 and then upgrade to 4

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 setup will work fine with Angular 4. It's because they are similar to each other (not like angular-js and angular 2, where ng2 have been mostly rewritten).

EDIT

As I mentioned in comment below, you should use:

`npm install --save auth0-lock`

and

`npm install --save angular2-jwt`

instead of:

`npm install auth0-angular`

There are more details available at Auth0 official webiste: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2

Alternatively, you can fork one of official Auth0 github samples for Angular 2+ and customize it for your use.

Auth0 Angular2+ samples: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angularjs2-systemjs-sample

Comment: how to configure and install Auth0 in my Angular4 Application.

i have  try to install Auth0 like this - 

npm install auth0-angular 

but i got this error,......

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):


npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: This is not how you implement Auth0. You should use `npm install --save auth0-lock` and `npm install --save angular2-jwt`. Please check the official Auth0 website, becase you seem to use something without any knowledge of it. Here's the link: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2

Comment: I Got an error like this 

Run This Comment -- 

npm install --save angular2-jwt


candidate-ui@0.0.0 D:\Amiti-OnlineTest\candidateUI
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.0.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@4.0.3
+-- angular2-jwt@0.2.2
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.3.0

Comment: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN angular2-jwt-ilocalstorage@0.1.25 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-jwt-ilocalstorage@0.1.25 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-jwt-ilocalstorage@0.1.25 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.

Comment: How did you initialized your Angular project? Log warns about missing `@angular/core` and several more packages.

Comment: These are my packages in Package.json

"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-jwt-auth": "^4.0.13",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.2",
    "auth0-lock": "^10.14.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }

Comment: The packages looks fine. I cannot provide you more help, because I don't know what's wrong here. I can either suggest: fork github Auth0 sample and work around it or reinstall angular cli + clean npm cache.

Comment: Now its work fine.  i am applied auth0 link directly and install jwt in An Angular4 Application now its working ,, Thanks you Guys

Answer (score 0):

angular2-jwt is deprecated. This means if you're using Angular 5+, you should use auth0/angular-jwt

More information:
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/449#issuecomment-353022577